# Remove elements if text matches a string in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following markup:

```
<div id="breadcrumbs">
  <ul>
   <li><span class="crumblink"><a href="/">Home</a></span></li>
   <span class="arrows"> »</span>  
   <li><span class="crumblink"><a href="/locations-brands">Publishing Regions</a></span></li>
   <span class="arrows"> »</span>  
   <li><span class="crumblink"><a href="/locations-brands/publications">Locations &amp; Brands</a></span></li>
   <span class="arrows"> »</span>
   <li><span class="crumblink"><a href="/locations-brands/publications/popupbrand">Publications</a></span></li>
   <span class="arrows"> »</span>  
  </ul>
</div>
```

How can I remove a `<li>` if has string "Publications" as well as its next `span.arrows`?

Comment: You realise that there are *no* elements, other than `li`, that can be a child of the `ul` or `ol` elements? Those `span`s invalidate your HTML. I'd suggest using [the ::after pseudo element instead](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cWjtH/1/) for that presentational aspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$('#breadcrumbs li:contains("Publications")')  
     /* find li node containing Publications */
  .next('span').remove().end()                
     /* search next span and remove it */
  .remove();                                   
     /* end() reset last selection (made with next()), so last remove() is removing the li */
```

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MZysf/

Comment: +1 This was exactly what I was going for, except cleaner. Nice solution.

Comment: You could probably explain a bit what your code does :), otherwise nice answer!

Comment: anyway take seriously into consideration what said @T.J. Crowder. : span are not allowed there

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to do this, but one would be to use [`$()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery) with a selector to look up the `li`s, then loop through them ([`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each) is handy for that) using [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text) to get their text, `String#indexOf` to check contents, and [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next) to see if the next thing is a relevant span (but see note below), and of course [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove) to remove an element.

When selecting the `li`s, you *can* use the special [`:contains("text")` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) jQuery adds, but note that if you do, it means jQuery can't use the browser's built-in tools for finding elements, and so there could be a performance impact.

---

Note that your HTML is invalid. [`ul` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-ul-element.html#the-ul-element) **cannot** have `span` elements as children; the only valid immediate children of `ul` elements are [`li` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-li-element.html#the-li-element) (which can have `spans` inside them if you like). What the browser does when you send invalid markup like that will be browser-dependent.